# Opening .msg files from sharepoint in Outlook

Tags: sharepoint-online, email, outlook, browsers

I'm looking for a way to open .msg-files, that are saved under our sharepoint online, directly with outlook (so I can reply, forward etc.) in stead of opening a preview in the browser (just like our word and Excel files). Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

In the new experience of SharePoint Online, it is the expected behavior that show the preview behavior.

If you wish to open the message in Outlook client, then you must download the file first.

Or Return to classic expernience, then you will open email file directly in Outlook client.

You can also submit your requirement about directly opening msg file with Outlook in the modern library (the new SharePoint library UI) via [Uservoice](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration).